# Is there a way to set conditions for end parameter in python?

Tags: python, list, variables, printing, nested-lists

I'm new to programming, just going through a wee online course, but I've hit a stumbling block on one of the tasks.

The task is to print the coordinates in the format of an 8 by 8 grid. So A1 to H1 is on the first line, A2 to H2 on the second, etc. The task is to be done using nested list comprehension where possible.

So far I have this, which puts all coordinates on the same line separated by a space:

```
let=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

[print(i,j,sep="",end=" ") for j in num for i in let]
```

I've tried some daft things that definitely do not work, such as:

```
let=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

[print(i,j,sep="",end=" " if i!=H) for j in num for i in let]
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line without typing out full "for" loops?

Comment: List comprehensions are meant to *build lists*, and should not be used for side effects (like printing, as you do here). Use normal loops.

Comment: And if you absolutely have to use list comprehensions, use them to build a list of sublists that you will `join`, and print the final result.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

[print(i,j,sep="",end=" ") if i!='H' else print(end='') for j in num for i in let]
```

but as the comment said, try using loop instead when you want to print things

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this in one line because it will print all the coordinates in one line, so you will need extra lines to arrange them in a grid but you can use this code :

```
let=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for i in num:
    x=""
    for k in let:
        x+=k+str(i)+" "
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some compromises need to be taken... single line + "print comprehension"... is quite unpythonic. The main problem to your question, to impose conditions on *print* parameters, is a bit hard because the parameters are *not callables*.... Here just some examples of usage.

Construct a single string with `\n` and *without* optional `print` parameters.

```
let=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

# for layout
col_sep, coords_sep = ' ', ''

print('\n'.join(col_sep.join(f'{i}{coords_sep}{j}' for i in let) for j in num))
```

Construct a list of strings, *with* optional `print` parameters

```
lst = [col_sep.join(f'{i}{coords_sep}{j}' for i in let) for j in num]
print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

---

**With conditions on *print* parameters**

The result should be properly design to make use of a "conditional" `end` parameter: construct out of the two given lists a flat list and then use modulo-arithmetic:

```
lst = ' '.join(col_sep.join(f'{i}{j}' for i in let) for j in num).split()
[print(term, end=(lambda x: ' ' if i % len(num) else '\n')(i)) for i, term in enumerate(lst, 1)]
```

`lambda`-part can be also replaced with `end=' ' if i % len(num) else '\n'`